# Sql Server Object Explorer - Strange Circular X icon

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I'm guessing this is some kind of issue with permissions?  I am using windows credentials, in fact, the exact same ones I log into SSMS(Sql Server Management Studio) with.  I can see my tables, views, and databases just fine with SSMS, but recently with SQL Server Object Explorer in VS 2013 Ultimate, I can't drill down to the tables....

Anyone have any clue as to what this circular X icon next to the table/database means?

[image]

Comment: I can write queries against the DB just fine in the query window, but for some reason I can't see the tables and use the GUI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having the same issue, its related to the Taiwanese language pack being missing(somehow it deletes it on its own, likely because you don't use it).  Anyways here is the MSDN link for the fix

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/923800/server-explorer-wont-show-table-data-for-local-db-version-11-in-vs-2013

I used this workaround listed by Shawn Steele and it fixed my problem!  I can now view tables and use the GUI.

Posted by Shawn Steele on 8/4/2014 at 12:03 PM

I don't have a repro, but I think what's happening is that a registry key is removed when the Taiwan language pack is removed (which can happen silently if you aren't using that language pack). This could be because the OEM provided the language as one of many in case the customer needed it, but when the user hasn't set it, Windows will remove it to free up space. The OEM may not notice because they're in Taiwan and wouldn't think to uninstall the language pack :)

If this happens, please try re-adding the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale registry key.

Either:

A) from an elevated command prompt:
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\ExtendedLocale

B) or in regedit, go to 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls
Edit->New->Key from the menu
“ExtendedLocale” for the name

This needs to be done AFTER the language pack is removed, so probably after you start seeing symptoms. As I mentioned, I don't have a repro machine, so please let me know if this fixes it for you.

Thanks,
Shawn